# How do inherit in Wpf that i do in windows form

Tags: wpf

in windows form i create a base form and inherit all my forms from that base one .

then with this way i can share all my **property** , **function** and **variable** that i want be in all forms . also this object oriented way help me to change all form fast with just change my base form

now i want know how can i do some thing like this in **WPF**

i handle share function with a public static class but i search for better way ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding WPF deriving WIndow class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174315/understanding-wpf-deriving-window-class)

Comment: Maybe it's a bad idea to use WPF if you want to use forms with variables

Comment: All the Windows and Pages have access to App.XAML but they don't derive from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class without design mode (xaml).

check this out 
[site reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/11/02/creating-a-base-window-class-in-wpf.aspx)