# Abstract class on XAML-Window

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, abstract

Is there any chance to add an abstract class to a wpf window?

Heres my Code so far:

My window:

```
 public partial class VORLAGE : Window, IWindow, IDisposable
    {
       //SOME CODE
    }
```

IWindow.cs:

```
public interface IWindow
    {
        void Open(MachineOrder machineOrder, Boolean showWindow);
        void OpenEditMode(MachineOrder machineOrder);
        void Close();
        void OpenManualOrder();
    }
```

There are a lot of windows based on that "VORLAGE" window and i want to add an abstract class to define some base functionality. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Am I understanding the question well? Create the abstract class, and let Window be it's base class.

Comment: I have a lot of windows which do the same thing. and i want to implement an abstract class to the window where i can define some functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just make your VORLAGE class abstract, and then make the other windows that share its functionality be child classes. For example:

```
// VORLAGE class containing the shared base code
public abstract partial class VORLAGE : Window, IWindow, IDisposable
{
    // Shared base code
}

// Your multiple window classes which utilize the same base code
public partial class MyVorlageWindowA : VORLAGE
{
    // Specific concrete code
}

public partial class MyVorlageWindowB : VORLAGE
{
    // Different, specific concrete code
}
```

Comment: sounds great, but i get an error: `partial declarations of must not specify different base classes`

Comment: It's been a while since I messed with XAML and partial classes, so I'm a bit rusty. Try leaving your concrete classes as partial, but take the partial keyword out of the abstract VORLAGE class definition.

Comment: the xaml's designer code should inherit from VORLAGE not Window. That's the other part of partial

Comment: the windows does not look excactly the same. is there a chance to overtake just a part of the designer?

Comment: That's the idea of using abstract classes. Your abstract class should serve as the template, containing only the same, shared code that all of your actual window implementations will use.

Then, in your concrete windows, you will program the specific components that make each window implementation different from one another.

Comment: i cant resolve this error `partial declarations of must not specify different base classes`

Comment: If you post the XAML code where you have designed one of the concrete windows, along with the actual abstract and concrete classes you're having issues with, it would probably help us out.

Comment: I tried doing it that way: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174315/understanding-wpf-deriving-window-class) but how can i set the style to WindowBase.cs if it doesnt have a designer?

Comment: WindowBase doesn't need a designer because it is not the concrete partial class being referenced as the x:Class of the XAML element. If you look at the XAML element in that answer, the x:Class attribute is set to the concrete partial class (MyVorlageWindowA in my answer) and the element's base class is set to the abstract base (VORLAGE in my answer).

Comment: so i cant set a button (for example btnProduce) to every window based on WindowBase.cs?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to inherit from `Window`, you don't have to inherit required features from abstract. You can bring those features as a sub component of that window, maybe using IoC.
2. You can make `MyBaseWindow` inheriting from `Window, IWindow, ...` and you can inherit other windows from that `MyBaseWindow`...