# How could providing Parent Window as Pattern - WPF

Tags: wpf, window-style

Consider I have 4 Window on my project and I try to provide specific Closing button and one Title

How could I make a object of window and all of window use it as Pattern.

Here is Example of what we have for pattern window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" >
<Grid>
<Button Content="Close" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" X:Name="WindowTitle/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

How could I use for all of my Window as pattern. Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174315/understanding-wpf-deriving-window-class

Comment: @Aaron It's okay, thanks, But How should I having specific Button on pattern ?

Comment: You would more than likely bind the base class button text and functionality to a property (or properties) in the base class. Then, when you set that property in child classes, the "OnPropertyChanged" notification will do whatever it needs to do to the button (add different handlers/bindings, remove unnecessary handlers/bindings, change text, etc)... Or, depending on how crazy it needs to be, you can create a 'base button' the same way you did your base window, and go totally nuts with it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. You may define a resource in a separate xaml file and use it in your other windows. check out "Merged resource dictionaries" section in the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references You need to define the resource and reuse it in your windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to write a **parent window**. You can use `Style` and `Template` instead. It's more convenient and is recommended by Microsoft WPF Team.

[image]

Write the code below into your `App.xaml` and you'll get the picture above:

```
<Application x:Class="Walterlv.Demo.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             .........>
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Style.Window.Default" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Close" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                <!-- This is the container to host your Window.Content -->
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And you can use only one property `Style` to share such a "pattern":

```
<Window x:Class="Walterlv.Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Style="{StaticResource Style.Window.Default}">

</Window>
```

You can define different kinds of styles in the `App.xaml` file and select anyone in your `XxxWindow.xaml` you need.

Comment: It's fantastic and it's what I need,Thanks