# WPF - A dialog having a base class other than Window, where that base class implements generics

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have kind-of a similar question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174315/understanding-wpf-deriving-window-class/7174427#7174427).

In a nutshell, if you create a dialog in WPF, you get from Visual Studio:

```
<Window x:Class="FrontEnd.View.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiabetesFrontEnd.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
        ...
```

created as part of the xaml, and

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
    ...
```

as the code behind. The questionner is asking about what happens to the xaml if you have a scenario with some base class scenario inserted, i.e.

```
   public partial class Window1 : BaseWindow
{
.....
```

where

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
...
```

My question is an extension to this. What if you have the above scenario, but with

```
public class BaseWindow<T> : Window
{
...
```

and I'd obviously also have

```
public partial class Window1 : BaseWindow<SomeConcreteClass>
{
...
```

Is it possible to represent this hierarchy in xaml? If so, what does the xaml look like? I'm specifically thinking of using generics here, as opposed to objects. I've just hit a scenario where generics looks useful, but I'm not sure how to achieve it in WPF where xaml is involved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the [x:TypeArguments directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-typearguments-directive) in the XAML markup.

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class BaseWindow<T> : Window { }

    public class SomeConcreteClass { }
}
```

**Window1.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class Window1 : BaseWindow<SomeConcreteClass>
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<local:BaseWindow x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        x:TypeArguments="local:SomeConcreteClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:BaseWindow>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8. I'm still thinking about whether generics is my best route but tested this and it works for me, so at least I know I *can* do it.